# Why can't I access vars loaded via file in Ansible?

Tags: variables, ansible

Why can't I access these Ansible file variables from within the Ansible task?

I've tried `vars_files` as well wit combinations of calling `global.varname` and `global[varname]`

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: True
  remote_user: root
  - include_vars: site_vars.yml
  tasks:
    - digital_ocean:
        state: present
        command: droplet
        unique_name: yes
        name: do_16_04_common
        api_token: "{{HOST_PROVIDER}}"
```

`global_vars.yml`:

```
global:
  WORKER_TAG_PREFIX:"dev"
  HOST_PROVIDER:"heroku-prod"
```

Error:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleUnicode object' has no attribute 'WORKER_TAG_PREFIX'"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your vars file is broken - it requires spaces between `:` and the values (and you don't need quotes for strings in this example):

```
global:
  WORKER_TAG_PREFIX: dev
  HOST_PROVIDER: heroku-prod
```

---

The above is the reason for the included error, but then the code has also syntax error which should be thrown first:

The correct syntax to include vars files at the play level is to define a [`vars_files` key](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-file-separation) containing a list of files:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: True
  remote_user: root
  vars_files:
    - site_vars.yml
  tasks:
    # ...
```

---

On the other hand, [`include_vars`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/include_vars_module.html) is a module (action) name for a task.

If you wanted to use it, you should add it to the tasks list:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: True
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
    - include_vars: site_vars.yml
```

Comment: Going with vars_files version but still getting same error.

Comment: try `api_token: "{{ global.HOST_PROVIDER }}"`